# Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, function, types

First of all, let me make it clear that what I'm looking isn't a union type but a straight up concatenation i.e `"Hel" + "lo" = "Hello"` but for string literal types

Essentially I have a function which takes two string literals, a `namespace` and a `name`, and combines these with a / in between as it's output, but I can't figure out a way to make the output a string literal and not a generic string.

I need it to be a string literal because the output will be used as a key of an object.

I've tried type intersections(`&`), `+`, `.concat()`

```
function makeKey<NS extends string, N extends string>(namespace: NS, name: N) {
    return namespace + '/' + name; // <- want this to be `NS + / + N` = `NS/N`
}
// I want this to return a string literal rather than a generic string

const objKey = makeKey('admin', 'home')
// I want typeof objKey to be a string literal: `"admin/home"`, not a generic `string`
```

typeof `objKey` is a generic `string` but I want it to be a `string literal` `"admin/home"`

Comment: Is string literal a separate type in typescript?

Comment: it's a subset of type string, more or less the same thing as string Enums

Comment: No, no current way to do it

Comment: The answer is unfortunately [no](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940).  There are several suggestions that might give you this functionality ([this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) or [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579)) but I don't think those are being considered.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn template literal are seperate things, string literals are typescript types

Answer (score 50, accepted):

TS4.1+ answer:

You can now use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to do this:

```
function makeKey<NS extends string, N extends string>(namespace: NS, name: N) {
    return namespace + '/' + name as `${NS}/${N}`
}

const objKey = makeKey('admin', 'home');
// const objKey: "admin/home"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBpTBPAHgDkBlRTADykzABMBnReqAJxjAHMAaRI8qmgyat2HAHwAKMKmSZ6AB1QRMALl4ke02WqIBKRAG8AsAChE5xC0xQQLJFrmLliANSIA5AHp3rxA8SojAAGACQGpAC+nmFEEUGmEaamEAjMiHAARgBWuHiIALwoGDj4Eu6otMjs7jzuABZwsu66ANymnp6IKWBpmTn4agBEFVVgng2yg0kmQA)

---

Pre TS4.1 answer:

The answer is unfortunately [no](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940). There are several feature suggestions filed in GitHub that, if implemented, might give you such functionality ([microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) to augment keys during mapped types, or [microsoft/TypeScript#6579](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) to manipulate string types via regular expressions) but I don't think they are being actively worked on.  I don't see anything in the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) about it, anyway.  If you really want to see this happen, you might want to go to one of those GitHub issues and give them a  or describe your use case if it's particularly compelling.  But I wouldn't hold my breath.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz ! I went ahead and left a comment on one of the threads with my use case.

Comment: I didn't know this was a thing. very cool, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It will be possible once **Template string types** will be released (looks like in typescript 4.1):

```
function makeKey<NS extends string, N extends string>(namespace: NS, name: N) {
    return (namespace + '/' + name) as `${NS}/${N}`;
}

const objKey = makeKey('admin', 'home') // objKey is of type 'admin/home'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-8#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBpTBPAHgDkBlRTADykzABMBnReqAJxjAHMAaRI8qmgyat2HAHwAKMKmSZ6AB1QRMALl4ke02WqIBKRAG8AUIlOIWmKCBZIpMuYuWIA1IgDkAejcvEWzPtRGAAMAEgNSAF8PMKIIoIBuIwijIwgEZkQ4ACMAK1w8RABeFAwcfAk3VFpkdjceNwALOFk3fQ8PTNz8xBhGOGBEKDx5THcqmrAPJpajIA)

---

> Template string types are the type space equivalent of template string expressions. Similar to template string expressions, template string types are enclosed in backtick delimiters and can contain placeholders of the form `${T}`, where `T` is a type that is assignable to `string`, `number`, `boolean`, or `bigint`. Template string types provide the ability to concatenate literal strings, convert literals of non-string primitive types to their string representation, and change the capitalization or casing of string literals. Furthermore, through type inference, template string types provide a simple form of string pattern matching and decomposition.

Some examples:

```
type EventName<T extends string> = `${T}Changed`;
type Concat<S1 extends string, S2 extends string> = `${S1}${S2}`;
type T0 = EventName<'foo'>;  // 'fooChanged'
type T1 = EventName<'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'>;  // 'fooChanged' | 'barChanged' | 'bazChanged'
type T2 = Concat<'Hello', 'World'>;  // 'HelloWorld'
type T3 = `${'top' | 'bottom'}-${'left' | 'right'}`;  // 'top-left' | 'top-right' | 'bottom-left' | 'bottom-right'
```

More details and examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Answer (score -5):

It worked for me, with typescript 3.7.2, using template literal to concatenate and the `as` keyword to specify the output type of my function .

```
const addSuffixToMyStringLiteral =
    (m: MyStringLiteral, suffix: string) => `${m}${suffix}` as MyStringLiteral;
```

I don't know if it a new feature of typescript or not.

Comment: The response type is of MyStringLiteral. OP expected e.g literalexamplesuffix.