# Typescript generic to turn underscore object to camel case

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface like this

```
interface Example {
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    home_town: string,
}
```

I am looking for a generic like `Camelize` that can take `Example` and switch all the keys to be valid if they are camelized instead of underscore.

```
const e: Camelize<Example> = {
  firstName: 'string',
  lastName: 'string',
  homeTown: 'string'
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot manipulate string literal types this way.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#6579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) and [microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) for related suggestions, with [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-517435342) especially relevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s)

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this with a [custom transformer](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/writing-typescript-custom-ast-transformer-part-1-7585d6916819). They aren't available to `tsc` unfortunately but you can use [`ttypescript`](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UPDATE for TypeScript 4.5:

With the introduction of [tail recursion elimination on conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types), it is now possible to write a version of `Camelize` that converts keys to camel case without running into recursion depth limits as easily as before:

The `CamelizeString<T, C>` type uses `C` as an accumulator to store intermediate results of turning the snake case string in `T` to the camel case string in `C`.

```
type CamelizeString<T extends PropertyKey, C extends string = ""> =
    T extends string ? string extends T ? string :
    T extends `${infer F}_${infer R}` ?
    CamelizeString<Capitalize<R>, `${C}${F}`> : `${C}${T}` : T;
```

The rest of the code is the same as the version below.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwFgAoZC5GYKAZzAH0RsIAuZeqUAcwBozKyPHHpMW7Tj37lKACwD2WCAzDyA7iAlguIPmQC+ZMmACeOFAGEWeYAC8IAZW08APABVkEdJBAATWsgAClDy5lCmANIQJrzIFp7eEH4BkrrIALzIAERZAHwZApQeXj7+HM5pAPzlOtwJpQEe1al1rIUUxYnJyAAGACSEoDDQyABi+gwDQyMASvo9yJXtcdZ2jhXcLlY4wGBwNvYuM7mx-YQW+gPjPfnsZxcDbvPI7G4A3EakpuYrSgcQ7nymUIyAA2hFkKBkABraLyGDIDwiX4Qf5OWouCK5AC6r3B2OQhlIxjMllW9gw2HwKEyVj+axclNwBFyH1IAHoAFTIb5k+kUzDMmnIEgyCjUOhgABy4hqPDZgmE9BlSi0tQVckUEDc6k0ct0bP0yE57M+CHkIHonnYdNRDKZ1KBIuWEuVsoA5C13dJFSJpR6vT7NUodRp2J6Nu6DJ9PkA)

---

TypeScript 4.1 introduced [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) and [key remapping  in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)), so you can achieve it this way:

```
type CamelizeString<T extends PropertyKey> = 
    T extends string ? string extends T ? string :
    T extends `${infer F}_${infer R}` ? `${F}${Capitalize<CamelizeString<R>>}` : T : T;

type Camelize<T> = { [K in keyof T as CamelizeString<K>]: T[K] }

type CamelizeExample = Camelize<Example>;
/* type CamelizeExample = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    homeTown: string;
} */

const e: Camelize<Example> = {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    homeTown: 'string'
}
```

The implementation of `CamelizeString<T>` finds the first underscore character (`"_"`) in a string `T`, removes it, and capitalizes the remainder of the string after recursively calling `CamelizeString` on that remainder.  And `Camelize<T>` remaps each key `K` of `T` to `CamelizeString<K>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwFgAoZC5GYKAZzAH0RsIAuZeqUAcwBozKyPHHpMW7Tj37lKACwD2WCAzDyA7iAlguIPmQC+ZMmACeOFAGEWeYAC8IAZW08APABVkEdJBAATWsgAClDy5lCmANIQJgB8yAC8yB5ePv4czrrIAPzpOtye3hB+AR45kpmsApTJhcXIAAYAJISgMNDIAGL6DM2t7QBK+vXZDc1dzVY4wGBwNvYuVkpzjhncLv0xMUPI7B67ANxGpKbmyIsQy+5xiYTIANoRyKDIANbR8jBJyCJn1nYreRcERiAF1dg8QchDKRjGZLH97BhsPgUIlzpckbgCDFDqQAPQAKmQJ3hS3+mJRCWQJBkFGodDAADlxLkeLjBMJ6MylFo8uy5IoIG51JpWbpcfpkAS8UcEPIQPRPOx0f8XBTsVSaYJ6VyWQBycrcPXSDkiJn6w3GqoUBRKYUadgG1Z6gxHI5AA)

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I ran into [some issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34933) with the types from @jcalz's answer. I found `CamelCasedProperties` and `SnakeCasedProperties` from https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest to work well so far.