# How can I specify types on a camel to snake case conversion function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that converts the case of a target string, array, or object from camel case to snake case.

```
convertCamelToSnake (target) {
  // Complex logic to convert target depending on what type it is
  return convertedTarget
}
```

I want to specify types on this function using a Generic like so:

```
convertCamelToSnake <T>(target: T):T {
  // Complex logic to convert target depending on what type it is
  return convertedTarget
}
```

This works for strings and arrays, but we convert the keys of a given object to snake case. But typescript doesn't realize this and assumes that the keys remain the same because we declare that we are returning `T`.

How can I retain the ability to know the type that is returned. I.e. string, array, object, while leaving the keys of the dictionary ambiguous?

For instance let's say we pass in:

```
const a = { helloWorld: "bob", age: 21 }
a = convertCamelToSnake(a); // { hello_world: "bob", age: 21 };
a.hello_world; // Property 'hello_world' does not exist on type
```

How can we make it so we're allowed to access the `hello_world` property after converting the object, while also still being able to infer that the return value is of type `object` (since we could for instance also be passing in an array into this function)?

Comment: It's not trivial, but @jcalz has a great answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932525/is-it-possible-to-use-mapped-types-in-typescript-to-change-a-types-key-names