# Create an alias name for a property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

context: I have to do a post request to a server with a body of interface with properties
title_string,created_at,etc

```
interface IPostBody{
      titleString:string;
      createdAt:string;
      ....
    }
```

I need to use this interface here

```
const requestBody:IPostBody={
  title_string:'hehe';
  created_at:'my home';
}
```

as you can see, the names don't match up so it will raise type missing errors.

is there a way I could solve this without changing the camelCase names in the interface definition

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX2LQm) where you transform the type `IPostBody` to a version with snake_case keys, as in `const requestBody: CamelKeysToSnake<IPostBody> = ...` .  Is that right?  (If so, then this question is probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932525/is-it-possible-to-use-mapped-types-in-typescript-to-change-a-types-key-names).  Let me know.)

Comment: @jcalz yea i guess its a duplicate , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could define a transformer function that will change the keys to camel casing:

```
function transformBody(body: any) : IPostBody {
 return {
   titleString: body.title_string,
   createdAt: body.created_at
   // and so on...
 }
}
```

Or create a function that automatically convert all keys to camcel case. See [Convert returned JSON Object Properties to (lower first) camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931828/convert-returned-json-object-properties-to-lower-first-camelcase)