# Custom computed method names within abstract class

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to create method names for an abstract class that are custom to that class. For example I'd like `UserRepo` to have `findUser` and `createUser` and `DogsRepo` to have `findDog` and `createDog`. Is this possible:

```
const x = (name) => {
    abstract class Repo {
        [`find${name}`] = () => {

        }
    }
    return Repo
}

class UserRepo extends x('User') {

}

const r = new UserRepo()

r.findUser()
```

Comment: You can do this at runtime, but TypeScript has no idea how to represent string concatenation at the type level.  There's a [suggestion to support this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) but it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s)