# TypeScript transform camelCase keys to snake_case

Tags: typescript

Imagine we have some type for a object with camelCase properties:

```
type Foo = {
  propertyBob: string;
  propertyJane?: number;
}
```

Is there some way to create a generic that converts the camelCase to snake_case? E.g.

```
type foo_snake = Snakeify<Foo>; 
/*
{
  property_bob: string;
  property_jane?: number;
}
*/
```

Comment: No, there is no string manipulation at the type level in TS.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) (particularly [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-517435342)), [microsoft/TypeScript#28329](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28329), and maybe [microsoft/TypeScript#6579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s) (The question is somewhat different but the answer is the same, as it has to do with type-level string manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

Now TypeScript has [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), so this is actually possible.

The [`type-fest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-fest) package implements several such converters for `snake_case`, `kebab-case`, `camelCase` etc.

This particular converter is the opposite of what you want, but it's the simplest to implement:

```
type SnakeCaseToPascalCase<S extends string> =
    S extends `${infer A}_${infer B}`
    ? `${Capitalize<A>}${SnakeCaseToPascalCase<B>}`
    : Capitalize<S>

const snakeToPascal =
    <S extends string>(s: S): SnakeCaseToPascalCase<S> =>
        s.split('_')
         .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
         .join("") as any

const pascalCase = snakeToPascal("get_abstract_singleton_manager")
// pascalCase: "GetAbstractSingletonManager"
```

Then you can use this converter together with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type SnakeToPascal<M extends Record<string, any>> =
    {[K in keyof M as SnakeCaseToPascalCase<K & string>]: M[K]}

type User = SnakeToPascal<{
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
}>
// inferred as: {
//    FirstName: string;
//    LastName: string;
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dig deeper I'd recommend: https://type-level-typescript.com/

But here is the answer to your question:

```
type Foo = {
  propertyBob: string;
  propertyJane?: number;
};

type CamelToSnakeCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}${infer U}`
  ? `${T extends Capitalize<T> ? "_" : ""}${Lowercase<T>}${CamelToSnakeCase<U>}`
  : S;

type SnakeCaseFoo = {
  [K in keyof Foo as CamelToSnakeCase<K>]: Foo[K];
};

const snakeCaseFooExample: SnakeCaseFoo = {
  property_bob: "hello",
  property_jane: 123,
};
```

Ok, so here is what's going on:

The type `SnakeCaseFoo` is an object, the key(s) of this object, which is a generic type that we are arbitrarily calling `K` has to be in the key of the Foo type, that's why we do `K in keyof Foo`.

Now, this key, we are going to cast it to something else. We are going to convert that key to camel_case.

The type of that key is whatever the type of that key was in foo, hence the `Foo[K]`. so, if the type of that key in Foo was a string then the new type for that key in our SnakeCaseFoo will also be string.

Ok, now lets move to the `CamelToSnakeCase` type:

This type gets a generic, which we arbitrarily call `S`, this generic has a restriction, it needs to extend from string (any string), or a type that is encompassed by the type string, like a string literal 'asdf'.

We then do a Conditional Type, which looks like this:

```
type TrueOrFalse = A extends B ? true : false;
```

This is similar to the ternary operator in JavaScript, but it's not the same. It is a TypeScript feature for types. Again, an amazing resource to learn more about it is https://type-level-typescript.com/

Now, we are going to do some pattern matching on a string literal. Our pattern match will take a character, which we call `T` and then the rest of the string, which we call `U`.

We then say: if `S` doesn't conform to our pattern then our resulting type is `S`, we don't transform it.
But, if `S` conforms to our pattern then we are going to return a new type, a type that is a transformation of that `S`.

So lets transform that `S` which is conformed of a character `T` and the rest of the string `U`:

If the character `T` is a capital (`T extends Capitalize<T>`) then we return `'_'` otherwise we return `''` followed by that same character `T` in lowercase, if it was already lowercase then it won't do anything to `T`, so we have the following examples just for this part:

```
if T is 'a' then it is converted to ''+'a' which is the same as 'a'.
if T is 'A' then it is converted to '_'+'a' which is '_a'
```

Then it recursively calls itself with the rest of the characters (`U`).

So, for a string `ptBob` the computation will do:

CamelToSnakeCase<'ptBob'>

- `T` is 'p' and `U` is 'tBob' => 'p' + CamelToSnakeCase<'tBob'>
- `T` is 't' and `U` is 'Bob' => 't' + CamelToSnakeCase<'Bob'>
- `T` is 'B' and `U` is 'ob' => '_b' + CamelToSnakeCase<'ob'>
- `T` is 'o' and `U` is 'b' => 'o' + CamelToSnakeCase<'b'>
- `T` is 'b' and `U` is '' => 'b' + CamelToSnakeCase<''>
- `S` doesn't conform to `${infer T}${infer U}` so => `S` which at this point is `''`

going up the heap we get 'p' + 't' + '_b' + 'o' + 'b', which is 'pt_bob'.

We have successfully turn the string literal type 'ptBob' to the string literal type 'pt_bob'.