# Typescript dymatic string as const

Tags: typescript

How to make this code work in Typescript;

```js
const prefixOne = 'ONE' as const;
const prefixTWO = 'TWO' as const;
const myStringGenerator = (prefix:string) => `${prefix}_STORE`;
const storeOne = myStringGenerator(prefixOne);
const storeTWO = myStringGenerator(prefixTWO);
```

`storeOne` and `storeTwo` is typed as string. What I want is:

```
const prefixOne = 'ONE' as const;
const prefixTWO = 'TWO' as const;
const storeOne = 'ONE_STORE' as const;
const storeTWO = 'TWO_STORE' as const;
```

`storeOne` and `storeTwo` is typed as `ONE_STORE` and `TWO_STORE`

Comment: You can't do this...

Comment: @Gerrit0 Is there a better way to do something like this? I'm using redux, but facing a problem that I can not write a reducerGenerator in ts.

Comment: Maybe ask about the real problem, about the reducerGenerator you want to write.

Comment: As of 2020 and TS 4.1, you can now do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do this in TypeScript.

Basically, you are asking TypeScript to evaluate anything on any step, that's not possible, you only get dynamic type, not dynamic value,

If you really want to do this, you can dynamically generate TypeScript source before your npm start scripts like this:

`node ./generateSourceCode.js && npm start`

and inside `generateSourceCode.js`, you just write things like this

```js
const prefixOne = "ONE";
const prefixTWO = "TWO";

const myStringGenerator = prefix => `${prefix}_STORE`;

const constants = {
  prefixOne,
  prefixTWO,
  storeOne: myStringGenerator(prefixOne),
  storeTWO: myStringGenerator(prefixTWO)
};

const sourceCode = Object.entries(constants)
  .map(([key, value]) => `const ${key} = ${JSON.stringify(value)} as const;`)
  .join("\n");

fs.writeFile("your file path", sourceCode);
```