# How to rebuild literal string keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

we know that we can use `keyof` to extract the key from an object.

```js
const a = { a1: 1, b2: 1, c3: 1 };

type AI = {
    [key in keyof typeof a]: boolean;
}
```

here we get new type

```
type AI = {
    a1: boolean;
    b2: boolean;
    c3: boolean;
}
```

but how can I rename the key，does any body know？

```js
type AI = {
    [key in ( 'prefix_' + keyof typeof a)]: boolean;// wrong
}

// here I want to get type
type AI = {
    prefix_a1: boolean;
    prefix_b2: boolean;
    prefix_c3: boolean;
}
```

Comment: You can't right now.  Go to [microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) and give it a  and/or describe why you need it if you think your use case is particularly compelling.  Good luck!

Comment: Will close this as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s) unless I'm missing some important difference