# How to create string literal type from nested object?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object of the form

```
const obj = {
  a: '',
  b: 0,
  c: {
     a: '',
     b: 0,
  },
};
```

Now I can create a type such as this:

```
type keys = keyof typeof obj;
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
type keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

but what I want is a type of the form:

```
type keys = 'a'
  | 'b'
  | 'c'
  | 'c.a'
  | 'c.b';
```

Would it be possible to construct such a type in TypeScript?

### My use case

So, I'm using [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store) to manage my config file.
This liberary exposes functions that accept string paths to object keys to return values.

```
import Store from 'electron-store'
const store = new Store();

store.onDidChange(
  'c.a',
  (newVal, oldVal) => console.log(`New: ${newVal} Old: ${oldVal}`)
);
```

I've wrapped the above call into a different function that returns an Observable.

```
function get$(key: string) {
  return new Observable((subscriber) => {
    store.onDidChange(key, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      subscriber.next({ newValue, oldValue });
    });
  });
}
```

And I am trying to get intellisense for valild key paths whenever I pass a string to get$ function so that I would not be able to pass any invalid key paths to the function.

Comment: No, there is no operator like concatenation on string literal types.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to have that type anyway. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334701/is-there-currently-anyway-to-concatenate-two-or-more-string-literal-types-to-a-s)

Comment: @tmhao2005 I've updated the question to include my use case.

Comment: @Sachin your use-case is interesting but I would say that's impossible with the current version of Typescript to meet your idea