# TypeScript dynamic union

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type "helper" which would translate to a union, perhaps best expressed through this snippet:

```
type emailResponse = {
  email: string
}
NetworkActions<"EMAIL", emailResponse>
// translating to a union
{type: 'EMAIL_LOADING'} | {type: 'EMAIL_SUCCESS', payload: emailResponse} | {type: 'EMAIL_ERROR'}
```

The first type variable needs to be used as prefix for the three types of the union. The second type variable needs to be passed down to the second type of the union.

Can this be achieved in TypeScript? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not currently possible it soon will be possible when typescript 4.1 is released (in November 2020).

```
type emailResponse = {
  email: string
}
type NetworkActions<P extends string, T> = 
  | { type: `${P}_LOADING` }
  | { type: `${P}_ERROR` }
  | { type: `${P}_SUCCESS`, payload: T }

type R = NetworkActions<"EMAIL", emailResponse>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBBC2CGBLANgJQgZzAewHYegF4oBvAKChgRQC4oNgAnRXAczIF8zRIoA5CMADu2RgGsAggGNgiPBgA8ABRgAPYBFwATDPSYtWAGigAVAHxRiFKAB9SUHhDoADACQklHAPoAZAPISACIAknwA4s5QXJR2JA7gTlBuHt4AoqiofqiR0bb2ji7unl4AygCqAMIVqSUlzsZg8CDI2PBadCZRZNwJUKiW-IIi4tKy8goARKkAshLBPhPGcEhomDj4EGZkQA)

More details in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Answer (score 2):

As in the question "[Is there currently anyway to concatenate two or more string literal types to a single string literal type in TypeScript right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54334701/1426891)", the ability to concatenate `"EMAIL"` with `"_LOADING"` to produce `"EMAIL_LOADING"` is a feature of [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336).

This became publicly available with [Typescript 4.1, released on November 19, 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/).

```js
type NetworkActions<A extends string, B> = {type: `${A}_LOADING`} | {type: `${A}_SUCCESS`, payload: B} | {type: `${A}_ERROR`}

type input = NetworkActions<"EMAIL", emailResponse>
// translating to a union
type output = {type: 'EMAIL_LOADING'} | {type: 'EMAIL_SUCCESS', payload: emailResponse} | {type: 'EMAIL_ERROR'}
```

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBBC2CGBLANgJQgZzAewHYegF4oBvAKChgRQC4oNgAnRXAczIF8yzRIoA5CMADu2RgGsAggGNgiPBgA8kmAA9gEXABMM9Ji1YAaKACEAfFGIleEOgAMAJCUkcA+gBkA8pIAiASX4AcTsOKAAfUht7JxdXAGUAVQBhJIBROLi7YzB4EGRseC06E1CI63BbKEdnN1TUVE9UEO4bKBYwAFdgSwEhUQkZOQVFACJUgFlJP3cR4zgkNEwcfAgzMgB6dagmeHxkeDk2bewoeCgO3HlcHgqobC7O7qsoqAByCan3D29-INfSyIVOjvSbTeLJNIZV7ZXL5Qp0eYodBYBQQAHlSDAj5guoNVD-IA) note nightly playground version `4.1.0-dev.20201015`