# Typescript - string concatenation as type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do some rudimentary string manipulations, as you're converting literal unions to type names?

Example:

```
type Strings = "Fork" | "Spoon";

type GetMethods = { // I want this to be automatically generated basing on Strings
   getFork: Function,
   getSpoon: Function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript v.4.1, (which [looks like it will be released in less than 2 weeks time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/upcoming/)) you can use [Template Literal Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/#template-literal-types) to do this really easily:

```
type Strings = "Fork" | "Spoon";

type FuncNames = `get${Strings}`;

type GetMethods = { [K in FuncNames]: Function }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwM5QLxQEQDEB7eAa1ygB88YxDDlcBuAKGdEinwFdkBjAOQCGAWwiYcAA1QRgAEgDecJGnQBfCSzbhoAcRkBZGQAtCAE3FR5UANoBpKCk48BIsQF0AXE77BE9VUA)

Prior to TS4.1, [it doesn't look like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300713/14357) this is possible.