# How to create dynamic typescript type: The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'AppActions'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, middleware

I'm using Typescript and react-redux, and I trying to make custom dynamic middleware for my API request.

Here is my code:

```
import { Dispatch } from "react";
import { errorHandler } from "../components/Layout/SnackBar/alert";
import { API } from "../_helpers/api";
import { getTheTime } from "../_helpers/constants";
import { AppActions, AppState } from "../_types";

export const BankPages = {
  posts: { name: "POSTS", api: "/post/v2" },
  lessons: { name: "LESSONS", api: "/lesson/v2" },
  guides: { name: "GUIDES", api: "/lesson/v2/guide" },
  courses: { name: "COURSES", api: "/lesson/v2/course" },
  exercises: { name: "EXERCISES", api: "/lesson/v2?course=125" },
};

export const requestBank = (page: keyof typeof BankPages) => (
  dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>,
  getState: () => AppState
) => {
  const bankState = getState().bank[page];
  const currentTime = getTheTime();
  const resetTime = currentTime - bankState.nextLoad;
  if (bankState.data && resetTime <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  dispatch({ type: `REQUEST_${BankPages[page].name}` });

  API.get(BankPages[page].api)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: `SUCCESS_${BankPages[page].name}`,
        payload: {
          data: res.data,
          nextLoad: getTheTime(10),
        },
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => errorHandler(err, `FAILURE_${BankPages[page].name}`));
};
```

I get an error on **type** `dispatch({ type: ... })` : `The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'AppActions'`

This is what my type looks like:

```
export const REQUEST_POSTS = "REQUEST_POSTS";

export interface RequestPosts {
  type: typeof REQUEST_POSTS;
}
```

Everything works perfect, and I know it's because I declared `typeof REQUEST_POSTS`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The interface with `typeof REQUEST_POSTS` looks fine to me. what catches my eye is how you "build" your types for the dispatch. `type: 'SUCCESS_${BankPages[page]}'` this just looks wrong to me and it is probably not a useful string.

Comment: @ian Thanks for comment, which way you prefer to make dynamic string ?

Comment: The point is not about preference. `BankPages[page]` is not a string but an object. I don't know how you defined AppActions but it will probably not expect a stringified object. you probably wanted to add `.name`

Comment: thanks for the help `you probably wanted to add .name` ill work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search , I found a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300713/12608714) for making dynamic string in Typescript 4.1+ using function like this:

```
function makeType<NS extends string, N extends string>(namespace: NS, name: N) {
  return namespace + name as `${NS}${N}`
}
// should be used like this
const sampleType = makeType('REQUEST_', 'POSTS');
// return "REQUEST_POSTS"
```

Then for getting string as type, and make dynamic string from object should use `as const` like this:

```
export const BankPages = {
  posts: { name: "POSTS", api: "/post/v2" } ,
  lessons: { name: "LESSONS", api: "/lesson/v2" } ,
  guides: { name: "GUIDES", api: "/lesson/v2/guide" } ,
  courses: { name: "COURSES", api: "/lesson/v2/course" } ,
  exercises: { name: "EXERCISES", api: "/lesson/v2?course=125" },
} as const;
```

With this trick when you type `BankPages.post.name` shows you `"POSTS"` instead of `string`

And dynamic dispatch should be like this:

```
dispatch({ type: makeType("REQUEST_", BankPages[page].name) });
```